# In the words "repress" "pressure" "oppression," etc, why is one of the root component "per"?

Tags: etymology

According to [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*per-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_52721%27), definition (4) of "per", this root component formed words such as "repress," "express," etc. Except none of these words have "per" in them, only "pre." Incidentally, this is also the case in every other root definition on the same page, words forming in "pre," or even "pri" in "imprint", seem to have had the letter order, and in some cases the vowel flipped or swapped. Only in certain words, where the root meaning is different (definition (3)) do we find words like "perilous" or "expert" that do look the same (we also have another vowel swap with or "par" in "parlour").

Exactly what happened that it looks this way in virtually every single word, but the root element is different than the final result ("per" and not "pre")? What modified all these words and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Proto-Indo-European ablaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut), mentioned in another answer, explains e/o/ē/ō/∅ alternation, but not "pri" in "imprint", which is also mentioned in this question.

This is caused by a much later change, Old Latin vowel reduction.
Proto-Italic and Old Latin had accent on first syllable of word (it was diffferent in Classical Latin).
During some period of Old Latin, short vowels in non-initial syllables were reduced. Long vowels were affected only in last syllable, but diphthongs were affected somehow more. Details are complicated and may be reconstructed differently by different linguists. You can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Latin#Phonology), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin#Phonological_changes) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_phonology_and_orthography#Syllables_and_stress) page in Wikipedia.

Verb [premō, premesi /premezi/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/premo#Latin) had /e/ in initial syllable, so it was not affected by vowel reduction. However last vowel was reduced:

premō, premesi /premezi/ → premō, premere

Verb derived with prefix in- was originally:

in- +‎ premō, premesi /premezi/ → impremō, impremesi /impremezi/

/e/ in second syllable was reduced into eventually /i/:

impremō, impremesi /impremezi/ → [imprimō, imprimere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imprimo#Latin)

(Intervocalic s [z] changed to r [r] due to [rhotacism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin#S-rhotacism).)

English word [imprint](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imprint#English) comes, through Old French, from Latin imprimō, imprimere.

Comment: [This table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin#Phonological_changes) gives a better overview of the vowel developments than the three separate pages you link to; in particular, it explains why the first /e/ became /i/ while the second and third remained /e/. (We would actually expect the first /e/ to become _sonus medius_ [ɨ ~ ʉ ~ ʏ ~ ə] here, but there doesn’t seem to be any evidence for spellings in _†imprum-_, so it appears it simply became /i/, perhaps through analogy because it’s a transparent compound.)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: Your link is exactly the same as third link in my original answer. Sonus medius seems to have been spelled with <i> or <u> (table gives examples: docimentum, documentum, optimus, optumus, lacrima, lacruma), so it is possible that second vowel in <imprimō> was sonus medius for some time.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: Regarding "third remained /e/": As you probably heard, Latin infinitive was originally locative of athematic s-stem noun. See [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-os) (first *-os suffix which is athematic, not second suffix which is thematic). One of reconstructed variants of locative of this suffix in PIE is *-esi ((é) means accented e-grade of preceding root). Later development was, in Proto-Italic, quoting [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Italic_language#Obstruents): "*s was also allophonically voiced to *z word-medially.".

Comment: (Besides *-es and *-esi, another dialectal variant of locative of this suffix seems to have been *-esen, which gave rise to Proto-Hellenic *-ehen, next [Ancient Greek -ειν](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BD) (which is spurious diphthong and was pronounced /eːn/, never /ei̯n/ in earlier times).)

Comment: You’re right, that is the same as your second link! I must have clicked the wrong thing before and missed it. Regarding _sonus medius_, the thing is that there don’t seem to be any examples at all of **any** verb containing _premō_ where it’s written _-prumo_. If it had been _sonus medius_, we would expect that to be reflected in writing, just as it is elsewhere. This leads me to believe that in this group of words, the sound was always /i/, for whatever reason. Regarding the development of e’s, my point was just that you don’t specify in your answer that /i/ > /e/ at the end and /e/ > /i/ →

Comment: → in medial position are _both_ regular vowel reduction in Latin, even though they look like opposite developments on the face of it. Someone who reads the answer without knowing how Latin vowel reduction worked will likely be puzzled by this, but the table (which I had missed that you’d already linked to) gives a fuller overview that makes more sense of it.

Comment: About sonus medius, I see that you have written [question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/) in Latin section of StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, I got to wondering why it might be that there seem to be some groups of words that seemingly never exhibit this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple. The Proto-Indo-European language had vowel ablaut. This means the root vowel could manifest in several ablaut grades: as -e-, as -o-, as long -e-, as long -o- or disappear. When the vowel would disappear, it is said the ablaut grade was "zero-grade".

This means, the initial root *per- could inflect in various word forms or derivations to become *pr-.

So, it is conjectured that the PIE root *pres- meaning "to press" [is derived](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/pres-) from the root *per- "first, forward" by adding the suffix -es. Alternatively, it could be a separate, unrelated root.

Answer (score 0):

This is process called [metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)), and it is very common in language change. See the "English" section of that Wikipedia article for some examples of very familiar English words that have been shaped by metathesis.